# Runtime and Model time is not in sync in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on car workshop model which is similar to assembly line. I have setup a model time in properties as 8:00 AM. But when I run the simulation the model start working from 10:30 AM. I am not sure why this is happening. Could anybody help me to understand why these two time are not in sync.

Regards
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slFYw.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVMxU.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your simulation is running correctly, it starts at 8:00 am, and after 6.5 hours, it's 14:30

8+6.5 = 14.5

That means, that what you are printing on the console is wrong, and if you check that AWST is a particular timezone... check if you are using the correct timezone

Comment: ha, you are correct :D Didn't do the math right, removed my answer :)

Comment: Since i was using a TSGCore library, so there was predefined time zone. That was the main issue. Thank you. It it solved